# summarizing data in pandas by grouping data

Tags: python, pandas

This is as subset of a data frame:

```
         drug_id         A   B  C       type  
        lexapro.13      1               SSRI        
        lexapro.13      1       1       SSRI    
        lexapro.13          1           SSRI    
        lexapro.13          1           SSRI
        effexor.223             1       SNRI
        effexor.223         1           SNRI    
        cymbalta.18             1       SNRI    
        cymbalta.18     1               SNRI
```

As you see, the drug id repeated, but the values for A,B,and C are different. First I need to group data by drug_id and then for each group if A in any rows of that group (for example lexapro.13) has value "1", then A in that group has value "1', otherwise will get 0. IF B in any rows of that group has value "1", then B in that group will receive  "1", otherwise will get 0, and the same for "C". The output should be like this:

```
        drug_id         A   B   C   type
        lexapro.13      1   1   1   SSRI        
        effexor.223     0   1   1   SNRI    
        cymbalta.18     1   0   1   SNRI
```

I think at first I need to group the data by drug_id column using set_index, and then search for the value 1 in column A in that group, value 1 fro column B in that group and the same for C. But I do not know how to do it. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Is possible some another data as `1`, `NaN`s in columns `A,B,C` ?

Comment: yes, it  is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html), then replace `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), cast to `int`s by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and last if need column from `index` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.groupby('drug_id', sort=False).max().fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
       drug_id  A  B  C
0   lexapro.13  1  1  1
1  effexor.223  0  1  1
2  cymbalta.18  1  0  1
```

Another solution with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.any.html) check if at least one value is not `zero` or `NaN` per group and per column:

```
df = df.groupby('drug_id', sort=False).any().fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
       drug_id  A  B  C
0   lexapro.13  1  1  1
1  effexor.223  0  1  1
2  cymbalta.18  1  0  1
```

If need check only `1` values in all colums without `drug_id` is possible get all columns names with [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) and then compare with `1` by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['drug_id'])
df[cols] = df[cols].eq(1).astype(int)

df = df.groupby('drug_id', sort=False).max().reset_index()
#or
#df = df.groupby('drug_id', sort=False).any().reset_index()
```

EDIT:

If there is another `text` column, need [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) for aggregate each column, else column is omited.

```
d = {'A': [3.0, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0], 
    'type': ['SSRI1', 'SSRI2', 'SSRI3', 'SSRI4', 'SNRI5', 'SNRI6', 'SNRI7', 'SNRI8'], 
    'drug_id': ['lexapro.13', 'lexapro.13', 'lexapro.13', 
                 'lexapro.13', 'effexor.223', 'effexor.223', 'cymbalta.18', 'cymbalta.18'], 
     'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, np.nan, 5.0, 4.0, 1.0], 
     'C': [np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['drug_id', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'type'])
print (df)
       drug_id    A    B    C   type
0   lexapro.13  3.0  NaN  NaN  SSRI1
1   lexapro.13  1.0  NaN  1.0  SSRI2
2   lexapro.13  NaN  1.0  NaN  SSRI3
3   lexapro.13  NaN  1.0  NaN  SSRI4
4  effexor.223  NaN  NaN  1.0  SNRI5
5  effexor.223  NaN  5.0  NaN  SNRI6
6  cymbalta.18  NaN  4.0  2.0  SNRI7
7  cymbalta.18  1.0  1.0  NaN  SNRI8
```

Check values `1`:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['drug_id', 'type'])
df[cols] = df[cols].eq(1).astype(int)
print (df)
       drug_id  A  B  C   type
0   lexapro.13  0  0  0  SSRI1
1   lexapro.13  1  0  1  SSRI2
2   lexapro.13  0  1  0  SSRI3
3   lexapro.13  0  1  0  SSRI4
4  effexor.223  0  0  1  SNRI5
5  effexor.223  0  0  0  SNRI6
6  cymbalta.18  0  0  0  SNRI7
7  cymbalta.18  1  1  0  SNRI8
```

Dynamically prepare dictionary - for column `type` need another function.
Use [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first value per group or `join` for all values to `string` with all values:

```
d = {x:'max' for x in cols}
d['type'] = 'first'
print (d)
{'A': 'max', 'type': 'first', 'B': 'max', 'C': 'max'}

df1 = df.groupby('drug_id', sort=False).agg(d).reset_index().reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df1)
       drug_id  A  B  C   type
0   lexapro.13  1  1  1  SSRI1
1  effexor.223  0  0  1  SNRI5
2  cymbalta.18  1  1  0  SNRI7

d = {x:'max' for x in cols}
d['type'] = ', '.join
print (d)
{'A': 'max', 'type': <built-in method join of str object at 0x000000000B447340>, 
 'B': 'max', 'C': 'max'}

df2 = df.groupby('drug_id', sort=False).agg(d).reset_index().reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df2)
       drug_id  A  B  C                        type
0   lexapro.13  1  1  1  SSRI1, SSRI2, SSRI3, SSRI4
1  effexor.223  0  0  1                SNRI5, SNRI6
2  cymbalta.18  1  1  0                SNRI7, SNRI8
```

Comment: would you please explain how max() and and reset_index() work?

Comment: Thanks and why you did sort as "false" ?

Comment: `max` choose max value per group and aggregate data. I add `sort=False` for not sorting groupbig column  `drug_id` first, so same output as you need. If omit it, order is different only.

Comment: sorry. I also have a column (D) that all values are text. Since you use astype(int), it return error. I updated the question. Would you please check ?. sorry again.